Conditions for a required for a valid Probability Distribution
Suppose I have a Finite Mixture Model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), i.e. a weighted sum of $M$ component densities, $f_1(x), f_2(x), ..., f_M(x)$, as follows:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i f_i(x)
$$
where $w_i$ are the weights of the mixture components.
I read that for $f(x)$ to be a valid probability distribution, it must satisfy two conditions:

Non-negativity: For all $x$, $f(x) \geq 0$.
Normalization: The integral (or sum, in the discrete case) of $f(x)$ over all possible values of $x$ must be equal to 1.

I am trying to understand why these conditions are necessary. Here is my logic
Non-negativity: Some logical arguments can be used here:

Each $f_i(x)$ is a probability density function . If any weight $w_i$ was negative, then $f(x)$ could be negative, which would violate the non-negativity condition. Therefore, each weight $w_i$ must be non-negative.
Since weights are probabilities, they also cannot be greater than 1, so each weight $w_i$ must be in the interval [0, 1].

Normalization: This is some round about logic.
The integral of $f(x)$ over all $x$ is:
$$
\int f(x) dx = \int \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i f_i(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i \int f_i(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i
$$
Using the laws of probability, each probability distribution function within the mixture must integrate to 1:
$$
\int f(x) dx = 1
$$
We can write this integral to represent the integral of the Finite Mixture Model:
$$
\int f(x) dx = \int \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i f_i(x) dx
$$
I think we can switch the order of the summation and the integral:
$$
\int f(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i \int f_i(x) dx
$$
Now, each $f_i(x)$ is a probability density function, so its integral over all $x$ is 1. Therefore, we have:
$$
1 = \int f(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{M} w_i \cdot 1
$$
This concludes the proof: We have shown that for the Mixture Distribution to be a valid distribution: all weights must sum to 1, and all weights can only be between (0,1).
Is this analysis correct?
